# Speed Distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed

I came across a problem which reads:

> The speed distribution function of a group of *N* particles is given by:
>   $dN_v = kv\; dv\;     (V>v>0)$
>   $dN_v = 0  \;          (v>V)  $
>   (a) Draw a graph of the distribution function.
>   (b) Find the constant *k* in terms of *N* and *V*.
>   (c) Compute the average speed, rms, speed and the most probable speed in terms of *V*.

Can anyone please help me solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You are given the differential equation:
$$ \mathrm dN_v = k v \, \mathrm dv$$

Now just integrate on both sides, and you will get:
$$ \int \mathrm dN_v = \int k v \, \mathrm dv$$
$$ N_v = \frac 12 k v^2 $$

Since there are no particles above $V$, you will have to do this piecewise:
$$ N_v = \begin{cases} \frac 12 k v^2 & 0 < v < V \\ \frac 12 k V^2 & v \geq V \end{cases} $$

You should be able to plot this. Is is a parabola that bends to a fixed value at $V$.

You can plot this in Mathematica:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x <= 2}, {4, x > 2}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

The result looks like this, $V = 2$ here.

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2013-09-16/Untitled-1.png

In order to be a commulative distribution, you need to have $N_0 = 0$ and $N_V = N$. That is because in the interval $[0, 0]$ there must not be any particles, whereas in $[0, \infty)$, there must be all $N$ particles. Since they are only in the range $[0, V]$, this means the above $N_0 = 0$ and $N_V = N$. That fixes $k$ to:
$$ k = \frac{2N}{V^2} $$

Now you can put that $k$ into the $N_v$ function and calculate the parameters that you should calculate.